# Swift custom xib file is not centered correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, xib

I am having problems with my Xib UIView.I created an xib view, added it to a uiview class, and then called this class in the main viewcontroller. In my xib view I created a label which is centered there directly in the center. Only when I start my project is the view no longer displayed in the center:
[Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9Sa8.png)

But this is what my view looks like in the xib file:
[Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWRad.png)

Could it be that it is because of the navigation controller? Although I don't think so, because I also added the navigation controller to my xib file. By the way, my custom view is added to a scrollview in my main viewcontroller.

This is my custom view class:

```
import UIKit


class TimerView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!    
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TimerView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    }
}
```

and there I added it to the scrollview:

```
func setUpScrollView() {
    sequenzeScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width * 3, height: 0)
    sequenzeScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    sequenzeScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    sequenzeScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    sequenzeScrollView.delegate = self
    
    for i in 0..<3 {
        let timerView = TimerView(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height))
        
        sequenzeScrollView.addSubview(timerView)
    }
}
```

can someone help me with this? I would be really happy about that! Love greetings

Comment: you are probably missing `contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true`

Comment: should I call that in commonInit? If so, then unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: You should probably do the same for `timerView`, otherwise `frame` will be just ignored.

Comment: than you mean = false???

Comment: no, `true`. It means the system will look at `frame`. Otherwise `frame` is generated from constraints which you don't have. Anyway, constraints are the preferred solution.

Comment: Anyway, check view inspector and check the generated constraints.